# Centos/RHEL 8 - starting custom service using systemctl unit file not working

Tags: linux, centos, vagrant, systemd

I am referring this link to create a custom service [RHEL doc](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/chap-Managing_Services_with_systemd#sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_File_Create)

Creates a systemd service, by creating a simple script present in a location (other than /usr/local/bin..) with `chmod +ax` enabled.

Below script is what i used and placed under under `/home/vagrant/temp/test.sh`.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

MAX=500
i=0;
while true
do
i=$((i+1));
sleep 2
echo "$i = $(date)"
if [ $i == $MAX ]; then
  exit 0;
fi;
done;
fi
```

Created simple service (unit file) named `usr-print.service` under `/etc/systemd/system/`.

```
[Unit]
Description=Simple print service
After=network.target

[Service]

Type=simple
Restart=always
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal

ExecStart=/home/vagrant/temp/test.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I start the service using `systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl start usr-print.service` i get to see the service is not started but below exception.

```
● usr-print.service - Simple print service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/usr-print.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-08-02 06:10:39 UTC; 7s ago
  Process: 1504 ExecStart=/home/vagrant/temp/test.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 1504 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Aug 02 06:10:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 02 06:10:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 02 06:10:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Aug 02 06:10:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 02 06:10:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Simple print service.
Aug 02 06:10:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 02 06:10:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 02 06:10:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Simple print service.
```

But when I move the script and update usr-print.service unit file with  `ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/test.sh` the service starts as expected.

Is there a way to use the script directly at this location `/home/vagrant/temp/test.sh` and start the service?

Centos 7.8 - `ExecStart=/home/vagrant/temp/test.sh` in service file looks like working (shell is running)

Centos/RHEL 8 - `ExecStart=/home/vagrant/temp/test.sh` in service file DOES NOT work.

Per document there were changes done from init to systemctl in the boot process, is this to do with the security of the service.

---

journalctl -u usr-print.service

```
Aug 03 23:17:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 03 23:17:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 03 23:17:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling resta>Aug 03 23:17:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Aug 03 23:17:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Simple print service.
Aug 03 23:17:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Simple print service.
Aug 03 23:17:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 03 23:17:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 03 23:17:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling resta>Aug 03 23:17:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 03 23:17:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Simple print service.
Aug 03 23:17:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 03 23:17:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 03 23:17:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Simple print service.
```

Comment: Is SELinux running? I think if User= is unspecified these start as root, so it can probably read the file location, but if SELinux is in enforcing mode, I can imagine it would prevent you doing this. check `getenforce`. If it's in Enforcing mode, try `sudo setenforce 0` then attempt to start it again.

Comment: Also you have `StandError=journal` - do you you see anything helpful in `sudo journalctl -u usr-print`?

Comment: indicates failed to start simple print service - updated the last section above (in question)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski `getenforce` returned Enforcing, as mentioned i issued, `sudo setenforce 0` it work.. and now the `getenforce` is permissive.

Comment: Beyond this if Enforcing mode is needed, you would need to debug what SELinux is denying via something like `audit2allow` and set a correct context on the script file or `setsebool` to set the boolean that prevents systemd from touching /home (if that is indeed what's happening)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

One possible apporach,for running in local is to use below

`getenforce` was enabled enforcing mode on SELinux

`sudo setenforce 0` disabled it and put in permissive mode. now the service runs.

But this is not recommended in production env.

```
[root@localhost system]# systemctl status usr-print.service
● usr-print.service - Simple print service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/usr-print.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-08-03 23:20:27 UTC; 3s ago
 Main PID: 2839 (test.sh)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 2746)
   Memory: 956.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/usr-print.service
           ├─2839 /bin/sh /home/vagrant/temp/test.sh
           └─2842 sleep 2

Aug 03 23:20:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Simple print service.
Aug 03 23:20:29 localhost.localdomain test.sh[2839]: 1 = Tue Aug  3 23:20:29 UTC 2021
```

Comment: disabling SELinux isn't a solution, it's at best a temporarily workaround